# java undefined compile time constant

Tags: java, compilation, constant-expression

JavaSE 6 defines the rules of [Definite assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/defAssign.html)

However, it's possible to assign a compile-time constant's value to its own undefined value, which results in weird behavior:

`Main.java`

```
public class Main{

    public static final boolean CONST_TEST = Main. CONST_TEST;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("CONST_TEST="+ Main. CONST_TEST);

    }

}
```

Compile it:

```
$ javac Main.java
```

Run it:

```
$ java Main
```

Output:

```
CONST_TEST=false
```

Different data types take different values, for example a String is null, float is 0.0, boolean is false etc.

At this point, I get the feeling that somehow the compiler was tricked into producing unchecked constant assignment bytecode

Although in practice such a situation is an edge case, I am curious why the compiler can be tricked in this particular case

Comment: You mean it's defaulting to the default value?

Comment: This isn't undefined behavior. In the example, the value of `CONST_TEST` is guaranteed to be `false`.

Comment: This might as well ask "Why didn't the authors of Java think this needed to be forbidden?". It _does_ assign a final value (the default) to the `final` variable, and it is _not_ undefined behaviour, so it is not really breaking any rules.

Comment: I find it ambiguous, because basically you can read a constant's value before actually assigning it, while assigning a value should only happen once. So this means that the constant was previously assigned by the compiler, with the default value, which is an exception to the rule that "a constant can only be assigned once"

Comment: It's not ambiguous because the spec defines the behavior. It may be *counter-intuitive*, but that's something different.

Comment: It is counter-intuitive, confusing me. Could you kindly please quote the spec that defines this particular behavior as an answer?